# How to jump to a hyperlink and back to original section in pdf or html documents

Tags: hyperref

Consider the example below. Using `\hyperref[hello]{go to hello}` I can jump to last page but I cant find the way to hyperlink back to where I was (before i clicked) unless I scrolled back manually. My question is: Is there a way to jump to a hyperlink and jump back to the text in latex? Footnote seems to have that functionality by creating a little blue arrow next to the footnote. Is there anything similar for hyperlinks?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage(hyperref)
\begin{document}  
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\hyperref[hello]{go to hello}
\newpage
 bla bla

\newpage
 bla again

\newpage
 hi
 \label{hello}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: 1) How is this question related to `html` document, as your title suggest? 2) Some pdf viewers (Adobe Reader, okular, etc.) have a "back" button. The shortcut in okular, for instance, is `Alt` + `Shift` + `Left`. But yo want to edit your _document_, right?

Comment: There could be a way to make this work, but this requires there is *only* one link to the same target. The “go back” button or key shortcut of your PDF viewer is what you need.

Answer (score 4):

In general, it is *not* possible to specify the link target for going back, because it is not known, from where this place was reached.

Some PDF viewers support the `GoBack` action (the PDF reference only supports `PrevPage`, `NextPage`, `FirstPage`, `LastPage`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\label{sec:first}
\hyperref[sec:second]{Link to second section}
\newpage
\section{Second section}
\label{sec:second}
\Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{Go back}
\end{document}
```