# How to jump to a hyperlink and back to original section in pdf or html documents

Tags: hyperref, r

Consider the example below. Using \hyperref[hello]{go to hello} I can jump to last page but I cant find the way to hyperlink back to where I was (before i clicked) unless I scrolled back manually. My question is: Is there a way to jump to a hyperlink and jump back to the text in latex? Footnote seems to have that functionality by creating a little blue arrow next to the footnote. Is there anything similar for hyperlinks?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage(hyperref)
\begin{document}  
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\hyperref[hello]{go to hello}
\newpage
 bla bla

\newpage
bla again

 \newpage
hi
\label(hello)

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can create a similar hyperlink to jump back, just like you did jumping forward. It requires a link text or marker though. Your code doesn't seem to be related to R or markdown at all. So this seems like it's a LaTeX question, correct?

Comment: Note that your notation is wrong here: `\usepackage{hyperref}` and `\label{hello}`.

Comment: Question already asked at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/336993/34551

Comment: I did but I guess I was not in the right forum so that's why I posted it here instead