# How to back again to my \cite (page and paragraph) when I click to my reference in the end of thesis?

Tags: cross-referencing

I use this package

```
\usepackage[colorlinks = true, linkcolor = blue,
            urlcolor  = blue,
            citecolor = blue,
            anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}
```

to click in my cite to go my reference in the end of thesis, but How to back again to my \cite (page and paragraph) when I click to my reference in the end of thesis? 
my code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
            linkcolor = blue,
            urlcolor  = blue,
            citecolor = blue,
            anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
The integration of renewable-based DG's into sub-transmission and distribution systems has become one of the most interesting topics trends out nowadays. The tendency to rely on alternative sources of energy for their economic and environmental benefits and set aside traditional sources has led to a major development in distributed generation technology. Although the integration of DG in the electric network improve the network reliability and voltage profile and minimize the energy losses. The incompetent to properly integrate DG's into the network may affect the performance of the network and jeopardize its reliability. The impact of DG on the electric network May be attributed to the change in the short circuit level and altering the power flow in the network \cite{Meng}-\cite{Choudhary}. Therefore, the protection system may not be functioning as expected and intimidate the stability and reliability of the network \cite{Malmedal}.
\newpage

\begin{thebibliography}{3}

\bibitem{Meng}
Meng Yen Shih, Arturo Conde Enríquez, Zbigniew M. Leonowicz, \emph{"Mitigating the Impact of Distributed Generation on Directional Overcurrent Relay Coordination by Adaptive Protection Scheme,"}.\hskip 1em plus
  0.5em minus 0.4em\relax 2016 IEEE 16th International Conference on Environment and Electrical Engineering (EEEIC), 7-10 June 2016, Florence, Italy.

  \bibitem{Choudhary}
Choudhary NK, Mohanty SR, Singh RK, \emph{"Coordination of Over current Relay in Distributed System for Different Network Configuration"}.\hskip 1em plus
  0.5em minus 0.4em\relax Journal of Power and Energy Engineering. 2015; 3:1–9.

  \bibitem{Malmedal}
Malmedal, K., Kroposki, B., \& Sen, P. K., \emph{"Distributed Energy Resources and Renewable Energy in Distribution Systems: Protection Considerations and Penetration Levels"}.\hskip 1em plus
  0.5em minus 0.4em\relax In Industry Applications Society Annual Meeting, 2008. IAS'08. IEEE (pp. 1-8).
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if you cite `Malmedal` multiple times, where would the "3" link to. Or do you literally want the functionality of the "back" button in a web browser?

Comment: I agree with you about multiple times citation, I would be grateful if you could help me about "back button" like web browser.

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/424779/35864 can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the `GoBack` action as explained in [Can LaTeX remember from which page the user jumped when clicking on a reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/424779/35864). As I understand it this is not part of the PDF standard and therefore not guaranteed to work with every PDF viewer.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
            linkcolor = blue,
            urlcolor  = blue,
            citecolor = blue,
            anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@biblabel}[1]{[\Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{#1}]}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
The integration of renewable-based DG's into sub-transmission and distribution systems has become one of the most interesting topics trends out nowadays.
The tendency to rely on alternative sources of energy for their economic and environmental benefits and set aside traditional sources has led to a major development in distributed generation technology.
Although the integration of DG in the electric network improve the network reliability and voltage profile and minimize the energy losses.
The incompetent to properly integrate DG's into the network may affect the performance of the network and jeopardize its reliability.
The impact of DG on the electric network May be attributed to the change in the short circuit level and altering the power flow in the network \cite{Meng}-\cite{Choudhary}.
Therefore, the protection system may not be functioning as expected and intimidate the stability and reliability of the network \cite{Malmedal}.
\newpage

\begin{thebibliography}{3}

\bibitem{Meng}
Meng Yen Shih, Arturo Conde Enríquez, Zbigniew M. Leonowicz, \emph{"Mitigating the Impact of Distributed Generation on Directional Overcurrent Relay Coordination by Adaptive Protection Scheme,"}.\hskip 1em plus
  0.5em minus 0.4em\relax 2016 IEEE 16th International Conference on Environment and Electrical Engineering (EEEIC), 7-10 June 2016, Florence, Italy.

  \bibitem{Choudhary}
Choudhary NK, Mohanty SR, Singh RK, \emph{"Coordination of Over current Relay in Distributed System for Different Network Configuration"}.\hskip 1em plus
  0.5em minus 0.4em\relax Journal of Power and Energy Engineering. 2015; 3:1–9.

  \bibitem{Malmedal}
Malmedal, K., Kroposki, B., \& Sen, P. K., \emph{"Distributed Energy Resources and Renewable Energy in Distribution Systems: Protection Considerations and Penetration Levels"}.\hskip 1em plus
  0.5em minus 0.4em\relax In Industry Applications Society Annual Meeting, 2008. IAS'08. IEEE (pp. 1-8).
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you may also want to look into the `backref` option of `hyperref`.